# How to calculate document insertion time in MongoDB for varying document size

Tags: mongodb

I want to insert a csv file in MongoDB. One method to do that is to import using mongoimport command, but I want to calculate time taken to insert the documents of different size in a given collection. Please suggest how that can be calculated.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard Unix-ish utility time

```
time mongoimport --db MyDB1 --type csv --headerline --file abc.csv
```

It will give u three time real,system and user.
You can take real time for complete execution.